# How to automatically move subsequent conversation messages to a folder in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I started using the conversation view in Outlook 2010 and so far it seems that it really lags behind the webmail ways of handling conversations...

I've moved a conversation to a folder and I could not figure it out a way to configure it so that all the subsequent messages within the conversation are automatically moved to the same folder. Any ideas on how to do that?

Currently new messages arrive in my inbox and "break the conversation" until I move them manually to the same folder as the parent message

Answer (score 4):

If you right-click a conversation in the conversations view, you can go to Move > Always Move Messages in This Conversation.

[image]

I have not figured out how to make this apply automatically, *i.e.* all new emails move to the conversation's folder. If someone knows how to do that, please post a new answer.

Comment: That did the trick for me with manual move, but as you say it is NOT applying this to inbox rules

Answer (score 2):

In Outlook 2013, you can include messages from other folders on the View ribbon:

[image]

Not sure if that option is available for you in Outlook 2010.

Comment: This option is available in Outlook 2010. View ribbon → Conversations → Conversation Settings → Show Messages from Other Folders.